# Making an echo sketch using SoftwareSerial and Bluetooth

Tags: arduino, serial, bluetooth

In order to test my Arduino UNO + Sparkfun Bluetooth Mate Gold I've written this little sketch;

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

SoftwareSerial softwareSerial(8, 9);

void setup() {
  softwareSerial.begin(115200);
  softwareSerial.println("Bluetooth Ready.");
  softwareSerial.println("Waiting...");

 delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  int readByte;

  int bytes[10];

  int i = 0;
  boolean readSomething = false;

  softwareSerial.listen();

  long l = millis();
  while (millis() - l < 1000) {
    while (softwareSerial.available() > 0) {
      readByte = softwareSerial.read();
      bytes[i] = readByte;
      i++;

      readSomething = true;
    }
  }

  if (readSomething == true) {
    delay(20);
    readSomething = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
      softwareSerial.print(bytes[c]);
      softwareSerial.println(" ");
      bytes[c] = 0;
    }

    i = 0;
  } 
}
```

Now I'll connect through bluetooth via a terminal and send a string to Arduino, which will be written back.

If I send a string of '11111' for example, I would like something consistent back - the problem is that I get something that is not consistent!

Comment: I don't know a lot about Arduino, but are you sure that "SoftwareSerial" actually supports data rates as high as 115200? That would be awfully high for a bit-banged implementation.

Comment: Yes - i am sure. However, the problem persists with all the baud rates that I've tried. So I don't think that that is the problem.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Do you want to give us a clue about what's wrong with the data you get back, or do you want us to keep guessing? If you take the Arduino out of the circuit and just loop the data back at the Bluetooth module, does it work?

Comment: For example, if i send five 1s (11111) I get this back; 49, 152, 76, 166, 230 first time. Second transmit of the same string I get this; 49, 166, 166, 70, 243. I find it a bit strange that I get different numbers. Maybe there is a system to this, but it eludes me.

Comment: That's very interesting, because almost all of those numbers are bit-shifted versions of the correct value (49). The 70 is the only one that doesn't fit this pattern. This implies that one end or the other of the serial link between the Bluetooth module and the Arduino is losing track of the start/stop bits. Can you answer my second question above?

Comment: If I just terminal directly to the bluetooth module, I can put it into command mode and send commands and receive answers back just fine. I can also put the echo functionality on, and it works fine. I've also noticed some patch information in the SoftwareSerial.cpp in regards to a gcc version that was recently applied. I don't know if that is the problem, but bit-hunting is a bit out of my league. If you need more info, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: OK, I took a look at SoftwareSerial.cpp. It turns out that there are two very different implementations of it. The older version only supports one port at a time and is not interrupt-based. It's timing is very crude and I would not expect it to work reliably at 115200. The newer version is interrupt based, supports multiple ports (but only one receiving at a time) and appears to be much better written, with better timing resolution. Now, here's the question: Do you know which version you're using?

Comment: I'm using the version included in the Arduino 1.0.1 release for MacOS. I've pasted the source on the web so you can compare it with what you've found. SoftwareSerial.h (http://pastebin.com/8WTpUUAX) and SoftwareSerial.cpp (http://pastebin.com/t1K8a6LL).

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the newer one; it should be fine. I'm trying to think of a way to determine which end of the link is losing sync ... I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Can you write a sketch for the Arduino that simply prints "11111" and then pauses for 1 second, over and over again? See whether you can see that data correctly via the Bluetooth connection.

Comment: It's not the sending of chars from Arduino thats the problem. I made this code (http://pastebin.com/PwyM2D6M) and I keep it running and does not see a single error (all 1's). The faulty code, mine or SoftwareSerials, must be in the receiving part.

Comment: OK, we've definitely narrowed this down considerably. I think the next thing to try is to set the Bluetooth interface to use 2 stop bits, because the SoftwareSerial receive function seems to need more than one bit of "dead time" between incoming bytes at this speed. Go back to the echo sketch and see whether it works any better.

Comment: As I understand you, you want me to configure the Bluetooth module to use 2 stop bits. Looking at the documentation (http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf) I can only find one command that might do that, "SQ,256". I'm not sure that does what you intent, but I can tell you that if I send that command, I can't communicate to the device at all afterwards. I've also changed the settings of the  terminal (CoolTerm) that I use to connect to the bluetooth module afterwards - configuring that to use 2 stop bits as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, I think I've taken you about as far as I can. As I said at the beginning, I'm not an Arduino expert. I believe that the SoftwareSerial module is delaying the reenabling of interrupts too long, thereby missing the start bit of the next character. However, I'm going to have to defer to someone who knows a lot more about the Arduino run-time system and how libraries like SoftwareSerial interact with it.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling into this thread, I didn't find a solution - and have ended up using Arduino UNO's 0 and 1 (standard serial RX and TX) instead - and it works perfectly with 115.200 baud...

Answer (score 2):

if your problem is only in characters you receive back just use char[] array instead of int e.g.

**char** bytes[10];

Now you'll receive the same data back.

Hopefully it solve your problem